# Paypal - How to Create Payment on server side using PHP Laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal, server-side

I'm working on paypal express checkout now, and i have difficulties on create payment on server side, here is my code:

```
var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = '{{route('landing.paypalresponse', 1)}}';
var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/execute-payment';
var CSRF_TOKEN = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

    payment: function() {
        return paypal.request({
          method: 'post',
          url: CREATE_PAYMENT_URL,
          headers: {
            'x-csrf-token': CSRF_TOKEN
          }
        }).then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
            return data.id;
        });
    },

    onAuthorize: function(data) {
        return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
            paymentID: data.paymentID,
            payerID:   data.payerID
        }).then(function() {

            // The payment is complete!
            // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

what should i do on the server side?

how to create payment on my controller?

is that return a JSON array? or?

i have try to convert the object here:

[Paypal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create)

to array and return to my paypal button, but it return me this error

[Paypal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSgQ6.jpg)